# Executing a Activity of Web to run a WebJob inside Azure Pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, console-application, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I have two Webjobs that executes time consuming jobs via **.Net Console Application** and on completion of the first job I need to trigger the second job which is also a web activity followed by trigger a SSIS package.

What I have done is added a Web Activity which would call the WebJob via POST and and then added another Web Activity in the pipeline to call the second Job. Then on the Pipeline we have the SSIS jobs.

When I run the Pipeline the first Web Activity triggers the first Webjob with  HTTP post. I have configured to run the Second Activity on "Success" of the first one but it seems to be not waiting for the completion of first job. In pipeline monitor it shows the first activity "Succeed" and start execution of second activity where as the first application is still running in background.

I have also checked the POST request using POSTMAN to trigger the WebJob (which runs as first web activity in the pipeline), the response is "202 Accepted", which means the execution is not completed but is accepted for processing.  Is there any way to halt the execution until the first webjob completed process.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490480/how-to-get-response-from-a-long-running-webjob-in-a-azure-pipeline ?