# How to get response from a long running webjob in a azure pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

I have a web-job running a long-running console application. I am using the WebAvtivity to run the same in an Azure Pipeline and there is a dependant web-job next in the pipeline. When I am starting the pipeline the first job responses 202 and moves to next whereas I want it to wait till the first gets completed.

Is there a way to wait till I get 200 response of poll to the first web job to check the status?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to share how you are triggering the WebJob function in order for others to help.

I would suggest to look at the tasks "[Invoke REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=vsts)" or "[Invoke Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=vsts)"

Those tasks are built for the type of needs you are looking for as I guess your WebJob is using HTTP triggers.

You then can either parse the response or use a callback.